# Error with Memory Allocation: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff5f3ffff8)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

I'm working on taking a set of 40 digits and making a fibonacci sequence with the base cases two of those 40 digit sets. If I use just ints and no pointers with dynamic memory, it works fine, but when I actually use the Int40 struct, which is just a struct with int*digits in it, I get this thread error. I have no idea what this means and I've tried looking into it with other questions, but none of them help. Can anyone help me? The error takes place on line 6, with the ans->digits malloc

Thanks for taking the time!

```
Int40 *fibKw26(int n, Int40 *first, Int40 *second) {
    int count = 0;
    Int40 *arr = malloc(sizeof(Int40) * 3);
    if (count != n) {
        Int40 *ans = malloc(sizeof(Int40));
        ans->digits = malloc(sizeof(int) * 40);
        arr[0] = *first;
        arr[1] = *second;
        int x[40];
        int y[40];
        int m = 0;
        if (ans == NULL) {
            printf("Malloc error\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        if (ans->digits == NULL) {
            printf("Malloc error\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        for (m = 39; m >= 0; m--) {
            x[m] = first->digits[m];
        }
        for (m = 39; m >= 0; m--) {
            y[m] = second->digits[m];
        }
        int temp = 0;
        int carryout = 0;
        int carryin = 0;
        for (m = 39; m >= 0; m--) {
            //printf("%d + %d = ", x[m], y[m]);
            temp = x[m] + y[m];
            if (carryout == 1) {
                carryin = 1;
            }
            if (temp >= 16) {
                //printf(" equal or greater than 16 ");
                temp = temp % 16;
                carryout = 1;
                if (carryin == 1) {
                    //printf(" carried in ");
                    temp++;
                    carryin = 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                carryout = 0;
                if (carryin == 1) {
                    temp++;
                    //printf(" carried in ");
                    carryin = 0;
                    if (temp >= 16) {
                        temp = temp % 16;
                        carryout = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            ans->digits[m] = temp;
            //printf("%d -- Carryout = %d\n", ans->digits[m], carryout);
        }
        arr[2] = *ans;
        free(ans);
        return fibKw26(n, &arr[1], &arr[2]);
    }
    else {
        return &arr[3];
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I assume your structure Int40 is as something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int digits[40];
}Int40;
```

If that is the case, when you do:

```
Int40 *ans = malloc(sizeof(Int40));
```

You are actually allocating memory for all the 40 integers. So doing this:

```
ans->digits = malloc(sizeof(int) * 40);
```

Is totally wrong and unnecessary. And one more thing, assuming the code would work somehow:

```
    Int40 *ans = malloc(sizeof(Int40));
    ans->digits = malloc(sizeof(int) * 40);
    arr[0] = *first;
    arr[1] = *second;
    int x[40];
    int y[40];
    int m = 0;
    if (ans == NULL) {
        printf("Malloc error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
```

You are using the ans pointer on line 2, but you are testing it for NULL way down the code... This is wrong!!!

EDIT: Something else I saw:

```
arr[2] = *ans;
free(ans);
return fibKw26(n, &arr[1], &arr[2]);
```

You are freeing the memory for the ans, yet you try to pass the pointer to that memory to the fibKw26 function. The way you use arr is also wrong. Man, your code is a total mess. If you don't understand how the pointers and memory allocation/freeing works, better use arrays or sit down and study.